# Use postgresql COPY comand in php file

Tags: php, postgresql

Is it possible to use the postgresql `COPY` command in a php file?

I need to download table content from a database table to a file using a php script

```
    $sql = " COPY tablename TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ',' ";

    $db->query( $sql );
```

This code does not work for me, what is the right way?

Comment: "*not works*" is not a valid Postgres error message (and I doubt it's a valid PHP error message either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php provides [pg_copy_to](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-to.php) that implements `COPY` to a php array, one element per row.

```
$rows = pg_copy_to($connection, "tablename", ",");
```

Comment: But what if I don’t want to export a table but a query? And don’t want to get a rows array but stream to stdout?